# where is the jar file namingserver.jar in websphere application server installation files?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, websphere, websphere-7

Does anybody know where the jar file namingserver.jar can be found? I've searched through the websphere application server installation but found nothing. Additionally, I also tried to get one from the internet but have had no luck either.

WAS version: 7.0  ND

I need to get the following code working.

```
Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, 
        "com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory");
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,"iiop://localhost:2809");
InitialContext context = new InitialContext(env);
```

Answer (score 3):

I think what you really want to know is,

In which JAR does one find `com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory` and/or `javax.naming.InitialContext`?

On the server, the former is located in `com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar` inside the `/plugin` subdirectory of the installation root.  The latter is part of the JDK.

If you're intent is to run this code as a thin EJB client, then you want `com.ibm.ws.ejb.thinclient_7.0.0.jar` in the `runtimes` subdirectory of the installation root.

Answer (score 0):

Are you specifically looking for that class rather than that jar? Are you certain that class is in that jar? Try [this JSP to find which jar is providing the class](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mydeveloperworks/blogs/Dougclectica/entry/revive_finding_a_java_class_in_your_servlet_container2).

Answer (score 0):

To execute that code you will need the EJB thin client. You can find the corresponding JAR in the `runtimes` directory of the WAS installation.